Spring boot app with old version, maven can't download old version
I have one issue with maven, and he can't download me a older version of spring-boot-starter-parent, when I build spring project by starter.io, then is working,but when I change version to older starter-parent, he can't load it.
I want use a Java 10 for this project, that version is compatible with this version of spring , I think with every 2.x version.
When I put this version inside of pom file, then maven can't find path to download this depedencie

Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.7.RELEASE' not found

Aswell when I tried use mvn clean install  or + -U see this

"sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCe rtPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target and
'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10"

Look
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

any advice ?

First use a more recent version of spring boot, because that version is long end-of-life (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support) .... also would suggest to use a more recent version of JDK.... JDK17 or JDK 21...

can't ,when project running on java 10

resolved by adding certificate to exact java version.
keytool -import -alias yourFileName -keystore  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\lib\security\cacerts" -file downloadedFile.crt.
You have to download this certificate in your webrowser,when you click on LOCK icon near web adress, then on Certification is valid--> details--> export that file crt
